# How can I limit the max value of number?

Tags: php

I want to secure my page by checking if the value is digital (0,1,2,3) and if it is in the range from 0 to 120. I think `ctype_digit` function limits numbers, so can not be passed any negative number. How can I limit the max value in the simplest way?

```
if (!ctype_digit($_GET['category'] AND ...) die('');

if (!ctype_digit($_GET['category'] > 120) ?
```

I was thinkig about `intval` but it can pass negative numbers.

Comment: Just typecast it to integer with `(int)$_GET['category']` and check if it's >= or less than 120.

Comment: why do you compare a boolean value returned from ctype_digit with a number?

Comment: @N.B. A decimal number (42.384) would pass that but shouldn't

Comment: @N.B. 120pigs will be passed.

Comment: do you want to automatically correct invalid inputs like strings (`"foobar"`) or floats (`"12.5"`), or do you want to punish the user for providing invalid inputs? if you don't care about invalid input, just typecast it, as N.B. suggests. if you do, look into `preg_match("~^\w+$~D", $_GET["category"])`.

Comment: @jprofitt & Col. Shrapnel `(int)"42.384" == 42` and `(int)"120pigs" == 120`. i don't see the problem with N.B.'s suggestion.

Comment: @Basti "42.384" isn't a whole number and shouldn't pass. "120pigs" isn't a number at all. Take a look at the [`ctype_digit()` docs](http://us2.php.net/ctype_digit)

Comment: if "42.384" should not pass or just be converted to 42 is up to OP. he has not answered this question yet.

Comment: So what if "42.384" isn't an number? It will be coerced to the allowed range, therefore no harm can be done. If you're the nitpicking type, then yes - it's not an integer and shouldn't be passed. However, this isn't a college assignment and int typecasting / coercing to the range works and is allowed in real world. I'll excuse myself from further discussion because it looks like some "performance" benchmarks will be soon thrown in, and since this is a trivial problem with trivial solution - I see no reason to waste more time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!ctype_digit($_GET['category']) || $_GET['category'] > 120) die('')
```

Basically this says "If it's not a number or if it's larger than 120, stop"

Comment: as long as 0 is not a valid input i would suggest `!ctype_digit($_GET['Category']) > 0` if 0 is not valid, and >= if 0 is valid.

Comment: `ctype_digit` returns a boolean, so you cannot test for 0

Comment: oh sorry, my fault. for such form validation i always use the filter_var function. http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-var.php

Comment: and here's the english version of rufinus link :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 7):

You might want to take a look at [PHP's Data Filtering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php).

It provides a filter for your task (`FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`) which also accepts `min_range` and `max_range` parameters:

```
$value = filter_var($_GET['category'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
    'options' => array(
        // An optional default value
        'default' => 123,

        // Desired validation range
        'min_range' => 0,
        'max_range' => 120
    ),
));

// $value is FALSE when validation failed, or an "int" with
// the correct value.
```

Comment: for filtering the input superglobals you can also use `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'category', $options)` though it impedes on testing because you cannot set the input variables in your tests.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way:

```
function set_range($value, $minimum, $maximum) {
    return min(max($minimum, $value), $maximum);
}
```

Here's what we're doing:

1. compare the number with our minimum value, and take the highest number.
2. compare that result with our maximum value, and take the lowest number.

And here's a test:

```
// Check every fifth number between 0-60 and 
// set output to within range of 20 to 40.
//
for ($i = 0; $i < 60; $i += 5) {
    echo $i . " becomes " . set_range($i, 20, 40) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

If you want to check if a number is within a range, you could do this:

```
function in_range($value, $minimum, $maximum) {
   return ($value >= $minimum) && ($value <= $maximum);
}

echo (in_range( 7, 20, 40)) ? "yes" : "no";  // output: no
echo (in_range(33, 20, 40)) ? "yes" : "no";  // output: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this as some people might stumble here on the search for a way to this task based on the topic of your question.
Sometimes you just want to "limit the max value of a numeric variable".

```
$val=($val <= 120)?$val:120;
```

That's the best way I found within one line (a combination of min() and max() can do the same but it's much more calculation intense)
If the $val is larger than 120 it will be trimmed to 120, otherwise the original value is used.

Answer (score 0):

`if (is_int($_GET['category']) and $_GET['category'] > 0 and $_GET['category'] <= 120)`

This will check if the number is greater than zero and smaller or equal to 120.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the whole numbers.

Comment: $_GET["category"] will never be of type integer until you cast it, even if the user passed an integer. it will be of type string. test it out yourself `var_dump(is_int($_GET["test"]), is_string($_GET["test"]));`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!ctype_digit($_GET['category']) || $_GET['category'] > 120) //do whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!ctype_digit($_GET['category']) || $_GET['category'] > 120) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Make sure it is an integer.
$category = (int) $_GET['category'];

if($category<0 OR $category>120){
   // Code to be executed if the number is out of range...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but here's why what you had wouldn't work:

```
if (!ctype_digit($_GET['category'] > 120) ?
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The indicated part is inside the ctype call. So first PHP will check if the GET value is greater than 120, turning that into a boolean true/false. **THEN** the ctype is applied, which will always be false, as a boolean value is not a digit.