# How to check if string value returned from text input is integer

Tags: php

I have a form where users search for keywords.

I want to check if users submit a number (integer) instead of a keyword.

I use this:

```
$keyword = $_REQUEST["keyword"];

if (is_int($keyword)) {
  echo 'true';
} else {
  echo 'false';
}
```

but it always returns false even when the value submitted is integer.

Comment: That's because `$_POST` always contains strings, not integer values.

Comment: I tend to use [`ctype_digit()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php), but people do it lots of different ways.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php validate integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100022/php-validate-integer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I limit the max value of number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414851/how-can-i-limit-the-max-value-of-number)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`is_int` checks to see whether the variable is of integer *type*. What you have is a string whose characters happen to represent an integer.

Try:

```
if (is_numeric($keyword) && is_int(0+$keyword))
```

The `0+` will implicitly convert the following to a number type, so you'll end up with the numeric value of the string if possible. Calling `is_numeric` first ensures you aren't converting garbage.

Comment: there are many ways to do this but personally i prefer *explicit* conversions over *implicit* ones because they are much more expressive. also checking for the maximum integer size is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

`is_int()` is for type safe comparison, so the *string* that is received from the browser always evaluates to `false`.

If you really need to check if a variable is an `integer` you can use this handy function:

```
function str_is_int($number) {
    // compare explicit conversion to original and check for maximum INT size
    return ( (int)$number == $number && $number <= PHP_INT_MAX );  
    // will return false for "123,4" or "123.20"
    // will return true for "123", "-123", "-123,0" or "123.0"
}
```

**Note: you should replace PHP_INT_MAX with the maximum integer size of your target system - e.g. your database.**

---

[in the docs of `is_int()`](http://php.net/is_int) you can read this:

is_int — Find whether the type of a variable is integer

```
bool is_int ( mixed $var )
```

**Note:**

*To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/is_numeric).*

Example:

```
<?php
if (is_int(23)) {
    echo "is integer\n";
} else {
    echo "is not an integer\n";
}
var_dump(is_int(23));
var_dump(is_int("23"));
var_dump(is_int(23.5));
var_dump(is_int(true));
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
is integer
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Comment: is_numeric() works but I need to know also if number is integer.

Answer (score -1):

I think `ctype_digit()` will work in your case.

Comment: Please give some details. Or Place it in comments.