# Short cut for (if,and) statment

Tags: php

If there any way to write short cut code instead of this one

I want to say if page id is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 then show something and else show something else

```
<?PHP
if ($page[id]==1 || $page[id]==2 || $page[id]==3 || $page[id]==4 || $page[id]==5 || $page[id]==6 || $page[id]==7 || $page[id]==8 || $page[id]==9 || $page[id]==10){

echo "something";

}else{

echo "something else";
} 

?>
```

thanks
that would helps me a lot for longer example since the ids are numbers 1,2,3...etc

Comment: Use `$page['id'];` <- note the quotes around the id. Don't leave it unquoted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I limit the max value of number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414851/how-can-i-limit-the-max-value-of-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
<?PHP
if ($page['id'] >=1 && $page['id'] <=10){

  echo "something";

}else{

  echo "something else";
}
```

Comment: Ummm, very nice idea using >= and <= :) ~ thanks a lot it will helps me a lot instead of repeating || for 100 ids.

Comment: Note that this will also evalute the first block for any floats, e.g. 3.14 will be "something". On a sidenote, it should be $page['id']. Array keys may only be written without quotes when interpolating.

Comment: @Gordon that's true unless id has benn defined as a constant (if not, PHP treats it as a constant and issue a warning, if i remember well)

Comment: yes, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar

Answer (score 3):

In such cases you can usally use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) to compare a variable against a list of values. In your case you can combine it with [`range()`](http://php.net/range) (if it's a short consecutive numeric list) like so:

```
if (in_array($page[id], range(1,8))) {
```

Note that `$page[id]` should probably be `$page["id"]`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [**in_array**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
if (in_array($page['id'], array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)))
{
    echo "something";
}
else
{
   echo "something else";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use ternary operator as below

```
echo ($page[id] >=1 && $page[id] <=10)?"something":"something else";
```

you can also use in_array to do similar condition

Comment: Why would you convert this to ternary from an if statement?

Comment: I am highlighting an approach. Is it bad to show another approach. Its one liner, compact but can be bit slower I agree

Comment: It is not bad - I did not suggest otherwise. Whilst one line does make it short - it also reduces the readability significantly. I would not worry about any micro-optimisations here for speed.

Comment: it's called ternary, not tertiary

Answer (score 1):

```
if($page['id'] > 0 and $page['id'] < 11) {
    echo 'something';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use an if condition like `if($page[id]>=1 && $page[id]<=10)..`